# Sharing and Security model for local accounts: Any reason to use this Setting in a domain?

Tags: windows-xp, group-policy, remote-access

I am trying to solve an issue I have with logging into computers with local users remotely, and stumbled on this setting in GP on our Domain controller:

[image]

This might solve my problem, but than there is this little sentence:

[image]

And my question: If this setting ONLY works on Windows XP, which are NOT joined to a domain, why would I EVER want to put it in a GPO? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would not.  This is only intended to be used in `gpedit.msc`.